# jest - Cannot find module (3rd party library)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-google-maps

I setup jest according to the setup guide on the docs (though i'm getting this issue when using create-react-app so I don't think it's related to jest config)

In one of my tests i'm importing components from the `@react-google-maps/api` library (which I am one of the maintainers of) as so:

`import { LoadScript, GoogleMap } from "@react-google-maps/api"`

and when running the test I get an error:
`Cannot find module '@react-google-maps/api' from 'app.spec.js'`

I have no problem importing these components anywhere else, just in my jest test.

**Additional info:**

The `@react-google-maps/api` library has the following fields in it's `package.json`:

```
  "browser": "lib/index.js",
  "module": "lib/index.js",
```

and index.js looks like this:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var GoogleMap_1 = require("./GoogleMap");
exports.GoogleMap = GoogleMap_1.default;
var LoadScript_1 = require("./LoadScript");
exports.LoadScript = LoadScript_1.default;
var TrafficLayer_1 = require("./components/maps/TrafficLayer");
exports.TrafficLayer = TrafficLayer_1.default;
var BicyclingLayer_1 = require("./components/maps/BicyclingLayer");
exports.BicyclingLayer = BicyclingLayer_1.default;
var DrawingManager_1 = require("./components/drawing/DrawingManager");
exports.DrawingManager = DrawingManager_1.default;
var Marker_1 = require("./components/drawing/Marker");
exports.Marker = Marker_1.default;
var MarkerClusterer_1 = require("./components/addons/MarkerClusterer");
exports.MarkerClusterer = MarkerClusterer_1.default;
var InfoWindow_1 = require("./components/drawing/InfoWindow");
exports.InfoWindow = InfoWindow_1.default;
var Polyline_1 = require("./components/drawing/Polyline");
exports.Polyline = Polyline_1.default;
var Polygon_1 = require("./components/drawing/Polygon");
exports.Polygon = Polygon_1.default;
var Rectangle_1 = require("./components/drawing/Rectangle");
exports.Rectangle = Rectangle_1.default;
var Circle_1 = require("./components/drawing/Circle");
exports.Circle = Circle_1.default;
var Data_1 = require("./components/drawing/Data");
exports.Data = Data_1.default;
var KmlLayer_1 = require("./components/kml/KmlLayer");
exports.KmlLayer = KmlLayer_1.default;
var OverlayView_1 = require("./components/dom/OverlayView");
exports.OverlayView = OverlayView_1.default;
var GroundOverlay_1 = require("./components/overlays/GroundOverlay");
exports.GroundOverlay = GroundOverlay_1.default;
var HeatmapLayer_1 = require("./components/heatmap/HeatmapLayer");
exports.HeatmapLayer = HeatmapLayer_1.default;
var StreetViewPanorama_1 = require("./components/streetview/StreetViewPanorama");
exports.StreetViewPanorama = StreetViewPanorama_1.default;
var StreetViewService_1 = require("./components/streetview/StreetViewService");
exports.StreetViewService = StreetViewService_1.default;
var DirectionsService_1 = require("./components/directions/DirectionsService");
exports.DirectionsService = DirectionsService_1.default;
var DirectionsRenderer_1 = require("./components/directions/DirectionsRenderer");
exports.DirectionsRenderer = DirectionsRenderer_1.default;
var StandaloneSearchBox_1 = require("./components/places/StandaloneSearchBox");
exports.StandaloneSearchBox = StandaloneSearchBox_1.default;
var Autocomplete_1 = require("./components/places/Autocomplete");
exports.Autocomplete = Autocomplete_1.default;
```

Is my library missing any configs jest is looking for?
Thanks!
Uri

Comment: does react-google-maps have an index file in the root? if not you're path needs to point to the directory that has the exports